# Loading GIF form on a Windows console app using threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, winforms, animation

I have a main form which does processing for an extended period of time. Normally, progress bars are used to show either the loading status or simply show the program is still running/hasn't freezed.

For this form, I wanted to give it a more snazzy look by reusing a common loading GIF found on the web that many users would be familiar with.

This is how I implement said GIF:

```
ShowLoadingGif();

              //Heavy lifting

HideLoadingGif();

private void ShowLoadingGif()
{
    this.Enabled = false;

    Point formCenterPt = new Point()
    {
        X = this.Location.X + (this.Width/2),
        Y = this.Location.Y + (this.Height/2)
    };

    loadingThread = new Thread(() => ShowLoading(formCenterPt));
    loadingThread.IsBackground = true;
    loadingThread.Name = "Loading gif";
    loadingThread.Start();
}   

private void HideLoadingGif()
{
    try
    {
        this.Enabled = true;
        if(loadingThread.IsAlive)
        loadingThread.Abort();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log(String.Concat("Loading gif thread release failed: ",ex));
    }
}

private void ShowLoading(Point parentCenter)
{
    frmLoadingGif loading = new frmLoadingGif();

    Point offsetPt = new Point()
    {
        X = parentCenter.X - (loading.Width /2),
        Y = parentCenter.Y - (loading.Height/2)
    };

    loading.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
    loading.Location = offsetPt;
    loading.ShowDialog();
}
```

What this does is produces a loading GIF (I grabbed mine from [ajaxloader](http://ajaxload.info/)) in the center of the form while processing is ongoing, and also disables the form.

My question is, whether or not what I did was overkill for something as simple as an inprogresss status, or if using threads in this way is the best way to do it. I realize that using a control on the main form would have been easier, but I couldn't find a way to do so with a GIF while also making the background completely transparent.

Why have I chosen to use a form for showing the GIF?

The alternative would have been to add the picture box to the main form. However, this didn't seem the best solution because I wanted to center the GIF to the form itself, and with the `TableLayoutPanel` I was using, you can't simply change the location of a control in that manner (please correct me if I'm wrong here). I also wanted to keep the transparency, threading, and other attributes of the picturebox control separate from the main form so I could reuse it elsewhere.

Finally, I wanted to show the GIF loading on top of the current form, and not just in the corner/bottom in its own section like a progress bar would. As you'll see in the picture, the loading GIF is shown on top of the control behind it, a `DataGridView`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about threading, so I can't really comment on that, but there is an opportunity to extract some logic that I am sure is used elsewhere in your project. You have this in `ShowLoadingGif()`

> ```
> Point formCenterPt = new Point()
> {
>     X = this.Location.X + (this.Width/2),
>     Y = this.Location.Y + (this.Height/2)
> };
> ```

And this in `ShowLoading()`

> ```
> Point offsetPt = new Point()
> {
>     X = parentCenter.X - (loading.Width /2),
>     Y = parentCenter.Y - (loading.Height/2)
> };
> ```

I would create two functions that take a form as an argument and return a point representing the `StartingPosition` and center point respectively.

---

I'm not a fan of this `If` statement.

> ```
> try
> {
>     this.Enabled = true;
>     if(loadingThread.IsAlive)
>     loadingThread.Abort();
> }
> ```

First off, *at the very least*, `loadingThread.Abort` needs to be indented properly.

```
if(loadingThread.IsAlive)
    loadingThread.Abort();
```

But I still don't like it. Let's say down the road Mr. Maintainer realizes that something else should happen `if(loadingThread.IsAlive`. Then they do something like this.

```
if(loadingThread.IsAlive)
    loadingThread.Abort();
    foo.bar();
```

The problem here is, `foo.bar()` will ***always*** be executed, but it ***looks*** like it will only be executed `if(loadingThread.IsAlive)`.

So, there are really only two options in my mind.

1. Write it as a single line `If` statement.

   ```
   if (loadingThread.IsAlive) loadingThread.Abort();
   ```
2. *Or* put the braces in.

   ```
   if (loadingThread.IsAlive)
   {
       loadingThread.Abort();
   }
   ```

---

This also makes me uncomfortable.

> ```
> catch (Exception ex)
> {
>     Log(String.Concat("Loading gif thread release failed: ",ex));
> }
> ```

You're swallowing every possible exception with nothing more than a message in a log file. You should figure out which exceptions you can gracefully handle and catch only those.